# Inverse Kinematics - Bones doesn't show up

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

I'm very new to blender.
I did some tutorials building and rigging basic characters. Last week I decided to built my first charcter on my own. It took a long time but I'm happy with the result.
I followed this tutorial for character rigging: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYgznqvbisM
First time I did this rig with my first character, everything was great.
Now I'm trying to rig my new char, but it doesn't work.

Problem is when I try to setup the inverse kinematics the bones won't show up. I can`t select any of them.
I guess this might be a setup problem. As far as I know, I didn't change the basic setups (but maybe by accident...?).

Maybe one of you knows what I did wrong.

(I use blender in German - hope this is not a problem. Armature = Body. I was working in pose mode)

*I hope my character can be saved and I doesn't have to start all over again...* :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added a mesh as target. You have to add the armature instead, then you can select a bone.
Based on the screenshot, seems like your armature is not called "body", it is called "skelett"

Comment: Oh my gosh.... Yes! Problem solved. Thanks a lot (I have to learn a lot I guess... xD)